# Parse Path name and vendor extension from swagger Json Doc using C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, swagger

Hey I have generated a Swagger Json Doc with a vendor extension at Path (api Operation) level. Now I want to Parse all of the Path names (route) along with the vendor extension at GET/POST etc level. Is there any way to do this in DotNet Core 6 ?

I only know hoe to parse a json file with static field name.

Comment: Check out the [OpenAPI.NET](https://github.com/Microsoft/OpenAPI.NET) parser.

Comment: @Helen could you please be a little specific? I see this tool as a way to serialize into swagger Doc not the other way.

Comment: The OpenAPI.NET parser can both read and write OpenAPI definitions.

Comment: @Helen really thanks man! Finally, I was able to deserialize my swagger Doc using openAPI.NET .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Helen I was able to perform this task in the following way :

First You should install [openAPI.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OpenApi) and [openAPI.NET Reader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OpenApi.Readers) nuget packages.

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("yourswaggerDocfilename");
var doc = reader.ReadToEnd();
var openApiReader = new OpenApiStringReader();
var docDeserialized = openApiReader.ReadFragment<IOpenApiAny>(text, OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi2_0, out var _) as Dictionary<string, IOpenApiAny>;
var paths = openApidoc["paths"] as Dictionary<string, IOpenApiAny>;
foreach(var pathItem in paths)
{
    var methods = pathItem.Value as Dictionary<string, IOpenApiAny>;
    foreach(var methodItem in methods)
    {
        var operationFields = methodItem.Value as Dictionary<string, IOpenApiAny>;
        if (operationFields.ContainsKey("x-vendorExtension"))
        {
           var moduleNameObject = operationFields["x-vendorExtension"] as OpenApiString;
           Console.WriteLine($"{pathItem.Key} : {moduleNameObject.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

You can actually parse swagger Doc with

```
var openApiReader = new OpenApiStringReader();
var docDeserialized = openApiReader.Read(doc,var out _);
```

But this would throw an `OverflowException` when doc contains any value > `decimal.MaxValue` , since this nugget library uses `decimal.Parse()` internally to parse numbers from Doc.
See this [Bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/issues/1106) for more info.